# list all files in a directory with url path

Tags: node.js

I am serving a directory over my LAN with NodeJS and it works fine. What I am looking for is, how can I get the list of all file names inside the served directory remotely. How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** I am trying to access the list of file names from a separate  machine on the same LAN.

```js
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var morgan = require('morgan');

var app = express();

var accessLogStream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/access.log', {flags: 'a'});

app.use(morgan('combined', {stream: accessLogStream}));

var PORT = 5000;

app.use('/desktop', express.static('/home/lnx/desktop'));

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    console.log("error!!!");
    console.log(err.stack);
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello');
});

var server = app.listen(PORT, function () {
    var host = '192.168.3.76'
    var port = server.address().port;

    console.log('App listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

```js
//something like this
const fs = require('fs')

const folderURL = 'http://192.168.3.76:5000/desktop';

fs.readdirSync(folderURL).forEach(file => {
  console.log(file);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const fs = require('fs')

const folderURL = '/home/lnx/desktop';

fs.readdirSync(folderURL).forEach(file => {
  console.log(file);
});
```

Comment: No. This is to access the list of files on the same machine. What I want is to access the served directory on a separate machine which is on the same LAN.

Comment: Your question doesn't mention that.

Comment: I have edited my question to better explain what I need.